# JTextArea, getting last value to use as a counter

Tags: java, jframe, jtextarea

I need to make a GUI that will have a menu and in the menu, it allow the user to count up or count down. The problem is I have no idea how to get the last value in my `JTextArea` to either increase or decrease.

Below is what I thought of but using `getText` it get all the text which I only need the last one. What could I do to properly do this counter.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


class MyMenu extends JFrame{
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
JLabel Number;
JFrame frame;

public MyMenu(String title){
  super(title);
  JTextArea _resultArea = new JTextArea(20, 15);
  add(_resultArea,"Center");
  _resultArea.setText("0");
  setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  setJMenuBar(menuBar);
  JMenu CountMenu = new JMenu("Count");
  menuBar.add(CountMenu);

  JMenuItem Plus = new JMenuItem("Inc");
  CountMenu.add(Plus);
  Plus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              int temp = Integer.parseInt(_resultArea.getText());

              _resultArea.append(""+ ++temp);
           }

        });
  JMenuItem Minus = new JMenuItem("Dec");
  CountMenu.add(Minus);
  Minus.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

           }

        });
  JMenuItem Reset = new JMenuItem("Reset");
  CountMenu.add(Reset);
  Reset.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

           }

        });
  JMenuItem Quit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
  CountMenu.add(Quit);
  Quit.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

           }

        });  
}


public static void main (String [] args)
{
  MyMenu Homework = new MyMenu("MyMenu");
  Homework.setVisible(true);
  Homework.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
}
}
```

Comment: Please don't do this `""+ ++temp`, it's horrible to look at and slow. `String.valueOf(++temp)`.

Comment: What do you mean by "last value"?